# Best practice testing a service that creates an entity instance in phpunit 7.5 and symfony 4.3

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit, symfony4, stubbing

I have a question.

In my Symfony 4.3 project I have a service that contains a method in which an entity gets created and persisted. currently it is doing (new EntityName())->generateToken(), but now **I want to create a unit test for this service** (I know I should have made that prior to this code, but fact is I am extracting stuff from a bigger legacy system into its own little service and just copied the code)

I want to also be able to test if the token gets generated ok. I can of course just check if there is a string with a length higher then x characters, but would be better if I could just insert a phpunit stub object that generates the same token always so I can check if that on is created, of just a mock that checks if the method was called.

I was able to stub the TokenManager. Should I put some code in the persist method to check this token? Or how would I test this with phpunit ?

For my own feeling it is already wrong that the entity object is generating this token, but I can live with that for now.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that I am just plain stupid (well I already knew that for a long time but I just got reminded to it again) because testing the entity output should ofcourse be done in its own unit test... And I can just mock the persist function to see if it is called and that would be enough...

thanks anyway.